# 8.00GB RAM (3.22GB usable) in Windows 7 x64

Tags: windows-7, memory, 64-bit

I have set up Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit on my PC. I have 8GB RAM and my BIOS states the correct amount (8192MB), but Windows (System Manager) says I have 8.00GB (3.22GB usable). give me a solution. I'm tried this:

Run > MSCONFIG, open the Boot tab > click Advanced Options > make sure that Maximum Memory

but this wasn't helpful.

My Motherboard Details:

CPU Type : DualCore Intel Pentium, 3000 MHz (15 x 200)
Motherboard Name : Foxconn G41MXE
Motherboard Chipset : Intel Eaglelake G41
System Memory : 3296 MB (DDR3-1333 DDR3 SDRAM)

DIMM1: Kingston : 4 GB DDR3-1333 DDR3
DIMM3: Kingston : 4 GB DDR3-1333 DDR3

#### My BIOS Details:

BIOS Type : AMI (03/21/11)
Vendor : American Megatrends Inc.
Version : 080015
Capabilities : Flash BIOS, Shadow BIOS, Selectable Boot, EDD, BBS

#### System Properties :

[image]

#### Bios File :

[image]

What about Bios Update?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your system properties (`Control Panel` -> `System`) to your post?

Comment: Perhaps instead of listing what your BIOS can support, how about a list of the ACTUAL hardware involved? :)

Comment: are you using an original cd, some fake cd's parade as 64 but are really 32.. and allot of fakes look real..even activate..but months later de-activate.. but.. unless the motherboard has a memory hole, shows 8gb but reports less.. did you update bios?

Comment: It is also entirely possible that with 4 DIMM slots then the maximum each **slot** supports is 2GB, meaning that potentially only half of each of your sticks is being used...

Comment: Take a screenshot of the Resource Monitor, Memory tab.

Comment: Did you solve your problem? If yes, please look at http://superuser.com/questions/1165428/upgrade-memory-from-4gb-to-16gb-but-hardware-reserved-memory-got-8gb

Answer (score 15):

Enter the BIOS and go to *Advanced Chipset Features → North Bridge Configuration*, then change the setting *Memory Remap Feature* to *[Enabled]*.

From the [manual](http://www.foxconnsupport.com/download.aspx?models=&category=C000000001&series=&keywords=gxk8mc&GridShowResultChangePage=5):

> #### Memory Remap Feature
>
> This item is used to enable/disable memory remap feature. Its mainly for if you have a 64bit
> OS and 4GB of RAM. Basically it allows you to remap the overlapped PCI memory above the
> total physical memory.

If that alone doesn't help, download the latest BIOS update from [here](http://www.foxconnsupport.com/download.aspx?models=en-us0000483&category=C000000001&brand=en-us0000001&Series=en-us0000002&chipset=en-us0000138&keywords=&sort=BIOS) and follow the steps outlined in the tutorial [How to flash BIOS?](http://www.foxconnsupport.com/faq.aspx?models=&category=&brand=&series=&chipset=&keywords=How%20to%20flash%20BIOS?&type=).

Comment: Also ensure the BIOS is at the latest version, which currently is "964F1P10" dated 11/7/11 ([link](http://www.foxconnsupport.com/download.aspx?models=en-us0000483&category=C000000001&series=en-us0000002&keywords=&sort=BIOS))

Comment: System Properties : http://i1180.photobucket.com/albums/x413/shoino/MySystemProperties.png
Bios File : http://i1180.photobucket.com/albums/x413/shoino/FoxconnWebsite.png
What about Bios Update?

Comment: Thanks  Darth Android, techie007, ppumkin, Mokubai, Dennis...

how to create bootable disc for bios update?

Comment: There is no such this option for me! IS there anyway to remapping Memory? from somewhere else than BIOS?;;;;; Please look at this: http://superuser.com/questions/1165428/upgrade-memory-from-4gb-to-16gb-but-hardware-reserved-memory-got-8gb

Answer (score 6):

I too had a similar problem to this when I upgraded my pc from 2 x 2GB to 2 x 4GB and had a similar setup; Windows 7 64 bit, American Megatrends BIOS. Tried all the software solutions proposed in the answers but no joy.

For me the problem was that one of the memory chips hadn't been pushed in with sufficient force (I have the strength of a little wood nymph).

Answer (score 3):

You may need to find and enable "memory remapping" in your motherboard's BIOS/CMOS settings. Also, did you completely disable the Maximum Memory setting?

Comment: my "memory remapping" is enable..

Comment: There is no memory remapping option in BIOS! please look at http://superuser.com/questions/1165428/upgrade-memory-from-4gb-to-16gb-but-hardware-reserved-memory-got-8gb