# Windows 7 x64 reports 8.00GB installed ram, but only 3.47Gb usable

Tags: windows-7, memory, 64-bit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [8.00GB RAM (3.22GB usable) in Windows 7 x64](https://superuser.com/questions/372751/8-00gb-ram-3-22gb-usable-in-windows-7-x64)

Lenovo Z575 laptop with 8GB RAM
Windows Ultimate, 64-Bit, Service Pack 1, installed this evening with latest drivers etc.
AMD A6-3420M APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics 1.5 Ghz

System info shows RAM as 8.00 GB (3.47Gb usable)

Resource Monitor shows:
 4634 MB Hardware Reserved,
  734 MB In Use,
   95 MB Modified,
  593 MB Standby,
 2138 MB Free

Available 2738 MB,
Cached     699 MB,
Total     3558 MB,
Installed 8192 MB

Previous OS (Home Premium) showed 8GB and 7.5GB available but kept crashing recently so upgraded.

The question is how do I get the Hardware Reserved RAM back?

Comment: Check your BIOS settings. Most likely, it will be something called "memory remapping" that needs to be set to *on*. Also, check `msconfig` (boot->advanced->maximum memory).

Comment: Are you absolutely 100% certain you have installed the 64-bit version rather than the 32-bit version?  If you have not changed anything but reinstalled the OS and suddenly you only have 3.4GB usable then I would suspect you have the 32-bit version.  Under `Control Panel` -> `System` it definitely says `System Type: 64-bit Operating System`?  As David Schwartz mentions also [Check the memory remapping option](http://superuser.com/questions/372751/8-00gb-ram-3-22gb-usable-in-windows-7-x64)

Answer (score 0):

If you poke around in your system BIOS, you should find a setting which allows you to change the amount of RAM that is reserved for the use of your laptop's video card. You will likely find this already set to some outrageous value such as 4096MB. Lower this value and you will increase the amount of memory available to the operating system.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I have already looked at the system BIOS which comes up after pressing F2.  The screen is headed Phoenix SecureCore Tiano Setup and doesn't seem to have any options to change the memory settings.  I did read online a suggestion that the BIOS is locked but don't know how true this is.  I already checked msconfig.