# Win7 Professional x64 16GB (4.99GB usable)

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, memory

I've installed [Corsair Vengeance CMZ16GX3M2A1600C10, 2x8GB, DDR3-1600, PC3-12800, CL10, DIMM](http://www.ascent.co.nz/productspecification.aspx?ItemID=403714) and my BIOS picks up that there is 16GB, Windows says there is 16GB, CPU-z says there is 16GB. But it only says I can use 4.99GB out of 16GB.

Motherboard is [P55-GD65 (MS-7583)](http://www.msi.com/product/mb/P55-GD65.html#/?div=Overview)

> Supports four unbuffered DIMM of 1.5 Volt DDR3 1066/1333/1600*/2000*/2133* (OC) DRAM, **16GB Max**

**Windows**

[image: Windows Experience Report]

(Above screenshot specifies that I am on a  *System type: **64-bit OS***)

**CPU-z**

[image: CPU-Z Report]

[Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366778%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#physical_memory_limits_windows_7) says that the physical memory limit on a 64 bit win7 professional operating system is 192GB.

**Dxdiag Run Command**

[image: Dxdiag Report]

**BIOS Screenshot #1**

[image: BIOS Screenshot #1]

**BIOS Screenshot #2**

[image: BIOS Screenshot #2]

Why is my OS limiting me to just over a quarter of the available memory? is there anyway to increase it?

Comment: Have you checked BIOS to make sure it's not reserving any of it for CPU or something?  What motherboard or laptop are you using?  Can you update question with this info please?

Comment: where abouts in the BIOs would I check if any memory is being reserved for the CPU?

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not exactly sure - it's going to change a lot from computer to computer.  Can you try to google your specific computer, or maybe just poke around for a few minutes.

Comment: Please run memtest, located here, http://www.memtest.org/. Also play around with the DIMM slots and see if there are any problems with the motherboard. Update your question with your results thanks.

Comment: [8.00GB RAM (3.22GB usable) in Windows 7 x64](http://superuser.com/q/372751) [Windows 7 x64 reports 8.00GB installed ram, but only 3.47Gb usable](http://superuser.com/q/448664)

Comment: Thanks Sathya! I set it to 14,000 and I now have 13,000 available woot :D

Comment: @Killrawr great, please post a detailed answer as to what you did to fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it on my windows 7 PC by simply going into msconfig -> boot -> advanced options. And increasing the maximum memory and then running a reboot.